# How to make magento search returns only products from specific store in magento multistore website?

Tags: magento, search

I have a magento multi store.  When I search for a product in store A, it returns products from store B.  How do I restrict the search to only return products from store A when search is conducted in store A?

Answer (score 0):

If you asking about php code realization look my example below

```
//create product collection
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'); 
//.... //add necessary filters, conditionas, etc

$collection->addStoreFilter(); // add current store filter to products collection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also setup different folders for your stores to seperate them more:

e.g.:

```
de-de/
de-en/
ch-de/
ch-fr/
```

put in each folder the "errors" folder and the index.php. Edit the index.php and add at the end:

```
Mage::run('chde','store');
```

sure, depending on your whole store configuration.

In each template use either the `<base href>` or prepend any link with Mage::getBaseUrl()